# The variable a is a float and the variable b is a double . Write a statement that will

Tags: java

Answer in the book doesn't make any sense to me so here's the problem:

The variable `a` is a float and the variable `b` is a double . Write a statement that will assign the value of `b` to `a` without causing an error when the program is compiled.

Here's the answer I found in the book:

```
fvar = (float)dvar;
```

Whaaaat!????

Here's what I thought might work:

```
public class HelloWorld 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    float a = 7.5;
    double b = 12.25;
    a = (double)b;
  }
}
```

Haven't figured it out so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why would `a = (double)b` work, if you need to cast **from** `double` **to** `float`?

Comment: What exactly is unclear with `fvar = (float)dvar`? And why do you expect a cast to `double` work better?

Comment: I've tried casting with (double) and (float), still getting an error. FYI I'm just starting out with this java stuff....
fvar = (float)dvar is unclear because the variables are a and b ...

Comment: OK so , if I don't initialize a with any value and do initialize b, casting it as float works. Why can't a be initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer totally makes sense since a is a float value which is not as precise as b which is a double. [look here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Which out telling the compiler the type of the variable it only knows that these type doesn't match. Since both of them are floating point numbers, you can cast b (the double) to a (the float) which cause a precision loss because a double can hold more precise numbers than floats.

If you cast b to a float, you tell the compiler that is shall cut the number to a float.

Answer (score 6):

What author of the book wrote is correct

```
fvar = (float)dvar;
```

If we look at your line of code,

```
a = (double)b;
```

You are casting a double to double again. What you have to do is cast to float, which is written in book. The author is correct.

Comment: First off, I believe you!
Second off, I tried casting as float and it didn't work
so here's my code now:

    public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
 float a = 7.5;
    double b = 12.25;
    a = (float)b;
  }
}

and I get "/tmp/java_nvyAbf/HelloWorld.java:13: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float
 float a = 7.5;"

what did I botch this time?

Comment: OK so , if I don't initialize a with any value and do initialize b, casting it as float works. Why can't a be initialized?